# Warning for right constraints

Tags: ios, constraints, xcode7

I do following:

[image]

then it show this:

[image]

Where i am doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From iOS 8 onwards, `UIView` has a `layoutMargins` property and according to the [docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIView_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIView/layoutMargins):

> The side margins vary depending on the current size class, but can be
>   either 16 or 20 points (for a view that is UIViewController's root view)

So, if you want to make sure that your imageView goes "edge to edge", deselect the `Constrain to margins` option and set the four constraints to `0`